# Cannot verify Pascal's theorem

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

> In projective geometry, Pascal's theorem (also known as the hexagrammum mysticum theorem) states that if six arbitrary points are chosen on a conic (i.e., ellipse, parabola or hyperbola) and joined by line segments in any order to form a hexagon, then the three pairs of opposite sides of the hexagon (extended if necessary) meet in three points which lie on a straight line, called the Pascal line of the hexagon.

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_theorem))

So I'm given the following six points, which lie on the parabola $x+2y=x^2$: $a_1=(-2,3), a_2=(-1,1), a_3=(0,0), a_4=(1,0), a_5=(4,6), a_6=(5,10)$.

So I've drawn and redrawn my picture several times, but the points of intersection $G$, $H$, and $K$ do not line up as collinear. Can someone please point out my error?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you're choosing which lines to intersect. Which order did you choose for the points to make a hexagon?

Comment: I chose to connect $a_1$ to $a_3$, $a_2$ to $a_4$, $a_3$ to $a_5$, etc., to form a hexagon.

Comment: @WillJagy I don't think I need that intersection point of the lines 26 and 35.

Comment: I guess not, but your big mistake is drawing two disjoint triangles rather than one hexagon. You have triangle 135 and triangle 246, as near as I can make out.

Comment: Look at the first diagram at your source, the edges go ABCDEFA back to beginning

Comment: So. Could you please do your drawing again, same points but choose letters ABCDEF for your six points, then join AB, then BC, and so on.

Comment: @WillJagy If I join $a_1$ to $a_2$, $a_3$ to $a_4$, etc, then I won't get any intersections at all.

Comment: @sequence , they will meet, *if extended*. That's what "extended if necessary" means in the original statement.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Yes, if extended, they will intersect, but that is of no use, since there will be no hexagon and will be no three collinear points of intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I drew in the hexagram that comes from using lines 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 61. In fact, the lines do need to be extended a little outside. Note that I had to draw the $x$ axis in orange since it is the same as the line through points 3 and 4. Well, on the paper it is clearly orange, on this screen I am having trouble as red and orange appear the same

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't appear to look as a hexagon.

Comment: @sequence why do you think it should resemble a hexagon?

Comment: It is said so in the Wikipedia article which I've linked above.

Comment: As far as I know, the definition of "hexagon" in projective geometry is a sequence of 6 points and the six lines joining each of those points to the next in cyclic order.  So the configuration in the picture not only looks like a hexagon, it **is** a hexagon.

Comment: @sequence look at the first diagram in the upper right of the wikipedia article you linked, with the green background. The hexagon in that diagram is not convex, indeed it has self intersections inside...that is, more or less, the whole point of this, such self intersections. If you begin with a convex hexagon inscribed in a circle, the intersection points occur outside the circle.

Answer (score 1):

here is one legitimate set of labels and edges

[image]

Comment: How do you determine which one is legitimate if both appear to be hexagons?

Comment: (1,3), (3,5),(1,5) is a triangle. (2,4), (4,6), (6,2) is another triangle. A legitimate choice is any one where the six vertices are connected all in a sequence, such as (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,1). You can change the order, but it's got to basically be like that.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Do you mean to connect $a_1$ to $a_2$, $a_2$ to $a_3$, ..., $a_6$ to $a_1$? This will not yield the needed result.

Comment: If you connect the 6 points in the order you suggested, then the opposite sides $a_1a_2$ and $a_4a_5$ meet at the point $(\frac14,-\frac32)$; the opposite sides $a_2a_3$ and $a_5a_6$ meet at $(2,-2)$; and the opposite sides $a_3a_4$ and $a_6a_1$ meet at $(-5,0)$. The three intersection points all lie on the line whose equation is $2x+7y+10=0$. So you do get the needed result.

Comment: @AndreasBlass   just added in that diagram as a second answer